# Word Clock - Most efficient method of telling time

Tags: java, android

Suppose you are trying to create this clock:

[image]

I have a `TimerTask` which returns `int hour` and `int minute` every 10 seconds.

The first solution that occurred to me is multiple `switch` statements, but that can quickly spiral out of control. It would work, but there is probably a much more elegant solution to handle all the different cases. Do you have any better ideas?

All advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "but that can quickly spiral out of control" -- How so? There are a very finite number of cases, I think it would actually be relatively straightforward to do it with branching statements (`if`, `switch`).

Comment: It wouldn't be out of control, but I was thinking others might have a more elegant solution than multiple `if` and `switch` statements.

Comment: For something this small, I don't see the benefit of trying to be fancy. Also, it doesn't make much sense that your `TimerTask` ticks every ten seconds when your smallest increment is five minutes.

Comment: @Karakuri That's a good point about the `TimerTask`.

Comment: The reason why I don't like the timer task, whatever the period, is how are you going to sync it to the clock and maintain that sync? I would listen to [`Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK) event instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with switch it's totally doable but you can divide clock face into 12 pieces and then go without any switch statments.

```
boolean past = true;
int i = (minutes + 2) / 5; // +2 because if it's 58 min past 7 you wanna get 8 o'clock

if(i > 6){  //we're on the left side of clock face
i = 12 - i; 
hours++;   
past = false;
   }
}
```

All you have to do is add switch statment or an indexed array containing proper string values. For example:

```
String[] array = {"", "five minutes", "ten minutes", "quater", "twenty minutes", "twenty five minutes", "half"};
String result = "It is " + array[i] + ((i!=0)?(past? " past ":" to "):"" + hours_array[hours] + (i==0)?" o'clock":"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me group it for you.

---

"it is" and "o'clock" is fixed. don't include them.
**half - ten - quarter - twenty - five :** is the first group
**minutes to - past :** is the second group
**one - three - two - four - five - six - seven - eight - nine - ten - eleven - twelve :** is the third group

---

So Lets start with second group. if minutes are less than 30 "past", if it is more "minutes to" is true.
Then if "past" is true, the first group indicates to minutes (minutes- minutes%5), if "minutes to" is true then first group indicates to 60-minutes.
Also if "past" is true third group indicates to hours, but if "minutes to" is true third group indicates to hours+1.

---

```
        Date date = new Date();
        int hours = date.getHours();
        if (hours==0) hours = 12;
        if (hours>12) hours -= 12;
        int minutes = date.getMinutes();
        minutes -= minutes%5;
        // minutes could be more accurate
        if (minutes<30) {

            switch (minutes) {
            case 5:
                // turn on five
                break;
            case 10:
                // turn on ten
                break;
            case 15:
                // turn on quarter
                break;
            case 20:
                // turn on twenty
                break;
            case 25:
                // turn on twenty and five
                break;
            }
            // turn on "past"
            // put a switch here for the hours
        } else if (minutes == 30) { 
            // turn on half and past
            // put a switch here for the hours
        } else { // turn on "minutes to"
            switch (minutes) {
            case 35:
                // turn on twenty and five
                break;
            case 40:
                // turn on twenty
                break;
            case 45:
                // turn on quarter
                break;
            case 50:
                // turn on ten
                break;
            case 55:
                // turn on five
                break;
            // turn on "past"
            // put a switch here for the hours
        }
```

Code is not completed but it will give you an idea.